# My EJS file not giving appropriate result when using for loop

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on a To-do app following my instructor. My instructor's code was working while mine foe loop isn't working. Though almost all code is except variable names.

**App.js file**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var items = ["test", "test", "test"];

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    var today = new Date();
    var options = { weekday: "long", day: "numeric", month: "long" };
    var currentDay = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
    console.log(items)
    res.render("list", { kindofDay: currentDay, newListItem: items });
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    var item = req.body.newItem;
    items.push(item)
    res.redirect("/")
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

**List.ejs file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>To Do List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= kindofDay %></h1>
    <ul>
      <% for (var i = 0; i < newListItem.lenght; i++){ %>
      <li><%= newListItem[i] %></li>
      <% } %>
    </ul>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <label for="listItem">New Item: </label>
      <input type="text" name="newItem" id="listItem" />
      <button type="submit" name="button">Add</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Output at my local host 3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lidvk.png)

Answer (score 1):

//TYPING mistake in 'length' property name

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>To Do List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1><%= kindofDay %></h1>
    <ul>
      <% for (var i = 0; i < newListItem.length; i++){ %>
      <li><%= newListItem[i] %></li>
      <% } %>
    </ul>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <label for="listItem">New Item: </label>
      <input type="text" name="newItem" id="listItem" />
      <button type="submit" name="button">Add</button>
    </form>
  </body>
    </html>
```